# Best way to code for Java 7 task required other task to finish first

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I have one task that I start off immediately, various executors that run, but then I have a final task that must not run until the the first task has finished. I am some knowledge of concurrency, but things change so much I'm unsure what is the now the best/simplest approach ?

Comment: Take a look to the keywords future/success

Comment: It sounds like you want Guava's ListenableFuture

Comment: Had a look, but no I dont want  task 2  to run as soon as task 1 has finished, I want it to later, but only run if task1 has finished, sounds like COuntdownLatch will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[CountdownLatch](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) or a [Phaser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) (if the number of preceding tasks can change).

Comment: I know CountDownLatch but because only two tasks involved thought might be simpler version, never seen Phaser before thanks.

Comment: I ran first tasks in executor, and passed  countdownlatch to it so it so it could call countdown(), then called await() before starting second task so that it waits

Answer (score 1):

In your case there are a few simple solutions:

- to have the first task call the second task
- to have a shared "trigger", for example a CountdownLatch, to enable task1 to communicate to task2 that it has completed its job
- use a single threaded executor and submit your tasks in the right order

Comment: Sorry forgot to say the second task does not want to start as soon as task 1 finishes, it needs to run as the last thing, but must not start unless task 1 has finished, no other tasks are dependent on task 1

Comment: Then you must know how many those other tasks there are, and initialize the `CountDownLatch` to that number + 1. Each task must countDown the latch.